# VBA macro to move cells to a new sheet and removing cell headers in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a VBA macro to move contents on sheet 1 to rows on sheet 2. This is very similar to a question posted on here but I am unable to get the macro to work for me as I am not understanding the variable portion of the answer. [Previously Answered Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25069593/vba-macro-to-move-cells-to-a-new-sheet-excel-based-on-cell-content#)

We will be pasting a block of info into sheet one that looks like this, with all data in column A across multiple cells:
Issue Description: Testing.

Priority: Standard

Person Number:       xxxxxxx

Encounter Number: xxxxxxx

Reported By: John CC X. Smith May 12 2015 11:40AM TSTEST2 (jsmith)

Template Name: fts_clinical_guide_8310

So what we would like is for the information in the Issue Description cell to move to a row on Sheet 2 with the text after the ":" only and so on for the other cells. I also need all of the cell information to stay in 1 row when it gets moved to sheet 2. I hope this makes sense and I would really appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Edit: Here is the code I am trying to modify. It mentions the original answers "headers" that I would change later. For example it mentions MyID="" and I have no idea how to put info into the quotes to make it work.

```
Sub MoveOver() 

Cells(1, 1).Activate 

myId = ""
myTitle = ""
myAuthor = ""

While Not ActiveCell = ""

If UCase(Left(ActiveCell, 4)) Like "*ID*" Then myId = Trim(Mid(ActiveCell, InStr(1, ActiveCell, ":") + 1, Len(ActiveCell)))

If UCase(Left(ActiveCell, 4)) = "TITL" Then myTitle = Trim(Mid(ActiveCell, InStr(1, ActiveCell, ":") + 1, Len(ActiveCell)))

If UCase(Left(ActiveCell, 4)) = "AUTH" Then myAuthor = Trim(Mid(ActiveCell, InStr(1, ActiveCell, ":") + 1, Len(ActiveCell)))

If ActiveCell Like "*---*" Then
    'NOW, MOVE TO SHEET2!
    toRow = Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Sheets(2).Cells(toRow, 1) = myId
    Sheets(2).Cells(toRow, 2) = myTitle
    Sheets(2).Cells(toRow, 3) = myAuthor
    myId = ""
    myTitle = ""
    myAuthor = ""
End If

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

Wend
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, what have you tried so far ? do you have any code snippets you wrote ?

Comment: I have updated the question with the code I am trying to use. Thanks for your quick response!

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
Sub SpecialCopy()
    Dim trg As Worksheet
    Set trg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim lastRow2 As Long: lastRow2 = trg.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For i = 1 To lastRow ' assuming we starting from second row
        trg.Cells(lastRow2, i).Value = Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, ":")(0)
        For j = 1 To UBound(Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, ":"))
            trg.Cells(lastRow2 + 1, i).Value = trg.Cells(2, i).Value & Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, ":")(j)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

EDIT: I have edited the code, please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, this works except I would need the information to be split into cells across one row. My question was unclear on that part and i apologize for that. I would also need the header of each cell to be removed when it is added to sheet 2. So "priority: xxxx" when it is added to sheet 2 would just be "xxxx". Does that make any sense? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. Please check edited answer. Please accept the reply if you are satisfied with it

Comment: Actually that works really well! The last thing is that when i paste new info into sheet A and run the macro, it inserts the information into the same row on sheet 2. We would need it to go into the next available row. Would that be possible? Thanks again for all of your help, i am learning a lot from your code!

Comment: Thanks again for the quick response! This time it adds two rows in sheet 2 with the top row being the header info, such as "Priority" and in the second row it adds the header AND the information after the header. It would be great to only have the second row add to sheet 2 while removing the header of each cell.

Comment: I changed the 2 in the trg cells portion to 1 and it fixed the issue of the header and the following information from adding to the row but it is still adding a row above that with just the header info. Thoughts?